# Algo falla al setear el parametro en la consulta

Tags: java, hibernate

Estoy haciendo uan consulta en hibernate y me da un error al hacerla y creo que es un rerror al setear el parametro.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate ordinal parameter [1], expecting one of []
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.ParameterMetadataImpl.getOrdinalParameterDescriptor(ParameterMetadataImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.ParameterMetadataImpl.getQueryParameter(ParameterMetadataImpl.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingsImpl.getBinding(QueryParameterBindingsImpl.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.setParameter(AbstractProducedQuery.java:507)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.setParameter(NativeQueryImpl.java:613)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.setParameter(NativeQueryImpl.java:62)
```

Esta es mi consulta

```
public static ArrayList CiudadesDeUnPais(short id) {
        short p = id;
        String nombreCiudad;
        ArrayList<String> nCiudades = new ArrayList();
        Session sesion = NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        org.hibernate.Transaction tr = sesion.beginTransaction();
        Query consulta = sesion.createNativeQuery("SELECT city FROM City where country_id =:id", City.class).setParameter(id, p);
        nCiudades = (ArrayList<String>) consulta.getResultList();
        return nCiudades;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba a pasar el nombre del parámetro:

```
Query consulta = sesion.createNativeQuery("SELECT city FROM City where country_id =:id", City.class)
    .setParameter("id", p, Hibernate.INTEGER);
```

Otra opción es pasar el parámetro por posición, pero es más robusto pasarlo por nombre, por si la query evoluciona:

```
....setParameter(0, p);
```

Para más información: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setParameter(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)

Comment: era eso faltaban las comillas, pero ahora tengo otro error. al intentar meterlo en el array list me dice Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query

Comment: Prueba esta query: `"SELECT city FROM City city where country_id =:id"` Ten en cuenta que "country_id" debe ser el nombre del atributo en la entidad City, del atrbuto Java, no de la columna de BBDD.

Comment: Quizás sea mejor crear una nueva pregunta y añadir todos los detalles....